# Spring cache, cache to hard disk instead of ram?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am working on a classifieds website and I want to cache everything so I can to reduce the database load. By default caching stores everything in ram. Is there anyway to store the cache on the hard disk instead?

Comment: a quick look at the documentation shows that spring doesn't provide caching but delegates to various cache providers. Pick one that supports disc storage and configure it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the cache providers supported by Spring without further ado ehcache is one that supports overflow to disk.

See Spring Boot docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html and other questions here in SO: [Java ehcache disk store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732582/java-ehcache-disk-store)